# Issue with import 'logbook'

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, logbook

I installed logbook with my terminal using 
`conda install -c quantopian logbook` and It works just fine when I try to use it in a python script `file.py` but once I try to run the same code on a jupyter notebook, It throws error so as:

```
      2 
----> 3 import logbook
      4 import tempfile
      5 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'logbook'
```

Furthermore, the notebook and the installation was in same folder, If that does change anything. Also the python version used in 3.6.4

Looking forward to some help here!

thanks

Comment: you have two different versions of python ... in both places try `import sys; print(sys.executable);`  you may also want to print `sys.path`

Comment: @JoranBeasley.. Thanks for your response! This sounds very basic but, do you by any chance have any suggestions on how may I fix this? I had this similar issue with other module called twobitreader but then it worked just fine when i reinstalled it but this solution doesn't work for 'logbook'. comments?